# How to add a custom scaffolder to aspnet-codegenerator with dotnet core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, code-generation, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am trying to add a custom scaffolder to aspnet-codegenerator. My goal is to generate a service layer between the controllers and DbContext using the scaffolder.

I've forked the [aspnet/Scaffolding](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding) repository into [my own repository](https://github.com/bascoder/Scaffolding/tree/feature/service-generator) and tried to add a service option to the command line tool under the [`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc`](https://github.com/bascoder/Scaffolding/tree/feature/service-generator/src/VS.Web.CG.Mvc/Service) project.
However, when I try to include the customized `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` package into my sample asp.net mvc core webapplication it won't show the `service` option when I run `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator -h`

I've included to package with the following command in my webapplication:

`dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design -s C:\...\Scaffolding\src\VS.Web.CG.Design\bin\Debug`

How can I run the custom scaffolder in my sample webapplication?